# Copy rows that has atleast one null value in any column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have table_1 that has certain columns. I want to copy that data to table_2 that has atleast one null value in any column of table_1. For e.g. table_1 has three columns. Now, I want to copy those rows to table_2 that has atleast one null value in any of the three columns of table_1.

I tried it using following query:

```
insert into table_2 (col1, col2, col3)
select col1, col2, col3
from table_1
where col1 is null or col2 is null or col3 is null
```

**But, there is an issue that table_2 has a column 'error_value' which should contain data that indicates which column(s) has NULL value corresponding to that particular row** like it should mention 'col2 is null' if col2 has missing value in that row. If more than one column has NULL values, then it should mention about all those columns in 'error_value' column like 'col1, col2, col3' is null if all columns have missing values.

Any suggestions or help how can I implement it.

Comment: Please provide example data +  expected results.

Comment: So the data in `col1` through `col3` should be identical between the source smudge destination table, correct? It’s just a filtered view containing a subset of the records which are missing data, and including a new column summarizing what data is missing. Correct?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what the `error_value` messages should look like for cases where there is { 1, 2, 3 } missing values?

Comment: @JeremyCaney, it should indicate 'col1, col2, col3 is null' when all columns has missing values.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: @Zohar Peled SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE` expressions to get the null columns, then concatenate. As of SQL Server 2017 this can best be achieved with `CONCAT_WS` (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
insert into table_2 (col1, col2, col3, error_value)
select
  col1, col2, col3,
  concat_ws(', ',
    case when col1 is null then 'col1' end,
    case when col2 is null then 'col2' end,
    case when col3 is null then 'col3' end
  ) + ' is null'
from table_1
where col1 is null or col2 is null or col3 is null;
```

Comment: Yes, for 2017, that's a better option than my answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
2017 version introduced `concat_ws` which can simplify the code significantly - check out [Thorsten Kettner's answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60845053/3094533). 
I'm leaving this answer here in the hope it will help some other reader that uses an older version of SQL Server.

**First version**
One simple solution would be to use a combination of `case`, `concat`, `stuff`, and the string concatenation operator (`+`), taking advantage of the fact that `concat` will implicitly convert `null` to empty strings, while `+` will not.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
create table table_1 (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);
create table table_2 (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, error_value varchar(100));

insert into table_1(col1, col2, col3) VALUES
(null, null, null),
(null, null, 1),
(null, 1, null),
(null, 1, 1),
(1, null, null),
(1, null, 1),
(1, 1, null),
(1, 1, 1);
```

Then, the `insert...select` statement:

```
insert into table_2 (col1, col2, col3, error_value)
select  
    col1, col2, col3, stuff(
        concat(
        ',' + case when col1 is null then 'col1' end, -- will be null if col1 contains a value
        ',' + case when col2 is null then 'col2' end, -- will be null if col2 contains a value
        ',' + case when col3 is null then 'col3' end, -- will be null if col3 contains a value
        ' is null'), 1, 1, '')
from table_1
where col1 is null or col2 is null or col3 is null
```

See a live demo on [<kbd>rextester</kbd>](https://rextester.com/SRKEU13681)

Answer (score 0):

How about below query using CONCAT and IIF:

```
    insert into
    table_2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    CONCAT(
        IIF(col1 is null, 'col1 ', ''),
        IIF(col2 is null, 'col2 ', ''),
        IIF(col3 is null, 'col3 ', ''),
        ' is null'
    )
from
    table_1
where
    col1 is null
    or col2 is null
    or col3 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with simple case statement and concat

```
INSERT INTO #table_2 (col1, col2, col3,error_value)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
,SUBSTRING(CONCAT(  CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN ',col1' ELSE '' END
                    ,CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN ',col2' ELSE '' END
                    ,CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN ',col3' ELSE '' END
                ),2,20) + ' is null'
FROM #table_1
WHERE col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NULL OR col3 IS NULL
```